# what will happen if so many classloaders occurs?

Tags: java, classloader

there exist an environment where I need many classloaders to load my new compiled class files. These classes have the same name, in order to make them different each other, I need different classloaders, and then, these things will happen many times at runtime, but we don't need them if they have loaded the new classes, which will let my application down? I am confused about that?

Comment: `I am confused about that?`me too... can you elaborate ?

Comment: "These classes have the same name," Why? As they are your classes, isn't it easier use different names?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What "thing" do you refer to in "these things will happen many times at runtime"? What do you mean about "let my application down"?

Comment: Using two different classes of the same (fully qualified) name should be avoided in nearly all cases.

Comment: (1) It's nearly always a bad idea to do this yourself. (2) That said, this is exactly how OSGi runs many large-scale systems (including Eclipse).